# Data structure / algorithm for query: filter by A, sort by B, return N results

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, indexing

Imagine that you have a large set of `#m` objects with properties `A` and `B`. What data structure can you use as index(s) (or which algorithm) to improve the performance of the following query?

```
find all objects where A between X and Y, order by B, return first N results;
```

That is, filter by range `A` and sort by `B`, but only return the first few results (say, 1000 at most). Insertions are very rare, so heavy preprocessing is acceptable. I'm *not* happy with the following options:

1. **With records (or index) sorted by B**: Scan the records/index in `B` order, return the first `N` where `A` matches X-Y. In the worst cases (few objects match the range X-Y, or the matches are at the end of the records/index) this becomes `O(m)`, which for large data sets of size `m` is not good enough.
2. **With records (or index) sorted by A**: Do a binary search until the first object is found which matches the range X-Y. Scan and create an array of references to all `k` objects which match the range. Sort the array by B, return the first `N`. That's `O(log m + k + k log k)`. If `k` is small then that's really `O(log m)`, but if `k` is large then the cost of the sort becomes even worse than the cost of the linear scan over all `m`objects.
3. **Adaptative 2/1**: do a binary search for the first match of the range X-Y (using an index over A); do a binary search for the last match of the range. If the range is small continue with algorithm 2; otherwise revert to algorithm 1. The problem here is the case where we revert to algorithm 1. Although we checked that "many" objects pass the filter, which is the good case for algorithm 1, this "many" is at most a constant (asymptotically the `O(n)` scan will always win over the `O(k log k)` sort). So we still have an `O(n)` algorithm for some queries.

Is there an algorithm / data structure which allows answering this query in sublinear time?

If not, what could be good compromises to achieve the necessary performance? For instance, if I don't guarantee returning the objects best ranking for their `B` property (recall < 1.0) then I can scan only a fraction of the B index. But could I do that while bounding the results' quality somehow?

Comment: are you using some database ? or things are serialized in a hard file ? or its in an array of objects in memory

Comment: the data fits in memory, so assume that. no database (i.e. in a sense the app is the database and the question is how to plan/answer this query:-)

Comment: are `A` and `B` integers ? or can `A` and `B` be translated to an Integer ?

Comment: yes, A and B are/can be integers. Also, in the more complex and specific problem I have in mind it might be possible to reduce A to a small number of possible ranges (e.g. 0-100, 101-200, ...) -- but the actual problem is much more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you are asking is essentially a more general version of:

> Q. You have a sorted list of words with a weight associated with each word, and you want all words which share a prefix with a given query *q*, and you want this list sorted by the associated *weight*.

Am I right?

If so, you might want to check this paper which discusses how to do this in O(k log n) time, where *k* is the number of elements in the output set desired and *n* is the number of records in the original input set. We assume that *k > log n*.

http://dhruvbird.com/autocomplete.pdf

(I am the author).

Update: A further refinement I can add is that the question you are asking is related to 2-dimensional range searching where you want everything in a given X-range and the top-K from the previous set, sorted by the Y-range.

2D range search lets you find everything in an X/Y-range (if both your ranges are known). In this case, you only know the X-range, so you would need to run the query repeatedly and binary search on the Y-range till you get K results. Each query can be performed using O(log n) time if you employ fractional cascading, and O(log<sup>2</sup>n) if employing the naive approach. Either of them are sub-linear, so you should be okay.

Additionally, the time to list all entries would add an additional O(k) factor to your running time.

Comment: I missed this answer. Thanks, I'm going to check it out ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

assuming `N << k < n`, it can be done in `O(logn + k + NlogN)`, similar to what you suggested in option 2, but saves some time, you don't need to sort all the k elements, but only N, which is much smaller!

the data base is sorted by A.

```
(1) find the first element and last element, and create a list containing these
    elements.
(2) find the N'th biggest element, using selection algorithm (*), and create a new 
    list of size N, with a second iteration: populate the last list with the N highest 
    elements.
(3) sort the last list by B.
```

[Selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm): find the N'th biggest element. it is `O(n)`, or `O(k)` in here, because the list's size is k.

**complexity**: 

Step one is trivially `O(logn + k)`.

Step 2 is `O(k)` [selection] and another iteration is also `O(k)`, since this list has only k elements.

Step 3 is `O(NlogN)`, a simple sort, and the last list contains only N elements.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I don't need the full sort. With the partial sort I can expand the usefulness of option 2, great answer. Still, when the filter makes k approach n (m in the original), it still degenerates into O(m) -- with worse constants. Any suggestions for that case? (I up-voted your answer, I'll accept the best one later).

Comment: Jim Mischel: yes, the problem remaining is that if k is not small, if it can approach m arbitrarily, then this still becomes linear. Any ideas for that? (still, amit's solution expanded the range that could be covered by option 2)

Answer (score 2):

If the number of items you want to return is small--up to about 1% of the total number of items--then a simple heap selection algorithm works well. See [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/). But it's not sub-linear.

For *expected* sub-linear performance, you can sort the items by `A`. When queried, use binary search to find the first item where `A >= X`, and then sequentially scan items until `A > Y`, using the heap selection technique I outlined in that blog post.

This should give you `O(log n)` for the initial search, and then `O(m log k)`, where `m` is the number of items where `X <= A <= Y`, and `k` is the number of items you want returned. Yes, it will still be `O(n log k)` for some queries. The deciding factor will be the size of `m`.

Comment: Hey Jim. If I understand, your proposal is similar to the adaptative option I outlined (plus amit's improvement): when your k is small, let the algorithm be bounded by the O(n log k) sort, otherwise just do the linear scan over B's index. But you rely on the heap selection for the details. So you think there's no guaranteed sub-linear solution for this?

Comment: You said that `k` is "1000 at most." If the list is very large (a million items or more), and you're only returning 1,000 items at most, then your problem isn't the size of `k`, but rather the number of items that have `A` within the bounds you specify. Although you might say my approach is essentially the same as amit's, "rely[ing] on the heap selection for the details" will typically give much better performance.

Comment: Jim, I was trying to understand the gist of your answer before getting lost in the details. I'll look into this more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) on A and, for each segment, precompute the top N in range. To query, break the input range into O(log m) segments and merge the precomputed results. Query time is O(N log log m + log m); space is O(m log N).

Comment: Wikipedia's segment tree article focuses on "given a point, find out which segments contain it". Are you proposing using the segment tree the other way around? Given the range segments, find out which points are in range? I'm having a hard time understanding the exact details of your proposed algorithm so far. Thanks for the answer, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a fully fleshed out solution, just an idea. How about building a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) on the A and B axes? You would walk down the tree in, say, a breadth-first manner; then:

- whenever you find a subtree with A-values all outside the given range [X, Y], you discard that subtree (and don't recurse);
- whenever you find a subtree with A-values all inside the given range [X, Y], you add that subtree to a set S that you're building and don't recurse;
- whenever you find a subtree with some A-values inside the range [X, Y] and some outside, you recurse into it.

Now you have the set S of all maximal subtrees with A-coordinates between X and Y; there are at most O(sqrt(m)) of these subtrees, which I will show below.

Some of these subtrees will contain O(m) entries (certainly they will contain O(m) entries all added together), so we can't do anything on all entries of all subtrees. We can now make a heap of the subtrees in S, so that the B-minimum of each subtree is less than the B-minimums of its children in the heap. Now extract B-minimal elements from the top node of the heap until you have N of them; whenever you extract an element from a subtree with k elements, you need to decompose that subtree into O(log(k)) subtrees not containing the recently extracted element.

Now let's consider complexity. Finding the O(sqrt(m)) subtrees will take at most O(sqrt(m)) steps (exercise for the reader, using arguments in the proof below). We should probably insert them into the heap as we find them; this will take O(sqrt(m) * log(sqrt(m))) = O(sqrt(m) * log(m)) steps. Extracting a single element from a k-element subtree in the heap takes O(sqrt(k)) time to find the element, then inserting the O(log(sqrt(k))) = O(log(k)) subtrees back into the heap of size O(sqrt(m)) takes O(log(k) * log(sqrt(m))) = O(log(k) * log(m)) steps. We can probably be smarter using potentials, but we can at least bound k by m, so that leaves N*(O(sqrt(k) + log(k)*log(m))) = O(N * (sqrt(m) + log(m)^2) = O(N*sqrt(m)) steps for the extraction, and O(sqrt(m)*(N + log(m))) steps in total... which is sublinear in m.

---

Here's a proof of the bound of O(sqrt(m)) subtrees. There are several strategies for building a quadtree, but for ease of analysis, let's say that we make a binary tree; in the root node, we split the data set according to A-coordinate around the point with median A-coordinate, then one level down we split the data set according to B-coordinate around the point with median B-coordinate (that is, median for the half of the points contained in that half-tree), and continue alternating the direction per level.

The height of the tree is log(m). Now let's consider for how many subtrees we need to recurse. We only need to recurse if a subtree contains the A-coordinate X, or it contains the A-coordinate Y, or both. At the (2*k)th level down, there are 2^(2*k) subtrees in total. By then, each subtree has its A-range subdivided k times already, and every time we do that, only half the trees contain the A-coordinate X. So at most 2^k subtrees contain the A-coordinate X. Similarly, at most 2^k will contain the A-coordinate Y. This means that in total we will recurse into at most 2*sum(2^k, k = 0 .. log(m)/2) = 2*(2^(log(m)/2 - 1) + 1) = O(sqrt(m)) subtrees.

Since we examine at most 2^k subtrees at the (2*k)'th level down, we can also add at most 2^k subtrees at that level to S. This gives the final result.

Comment: Erik, thanks for spending so much time on your answer. I'm trying to evaluate your proposal, but I'm not sure I understand some details. Can we start with the part about building the heaps?

Consider the easy case where [X, Y] bounds all elements; in that case S = {entire_quadtree}, right? I'm not sure I understand what the next step is. Is it that for each subtree in S you build a heap with the values of that subtree? In the case considered, to build a heap for a subtree with `m` nodes would take O(m) time, right? (not sublinear time).

Comment: 1. Correct, S = {entire_quadtree} - a singleton set with one entry, the whole quadtree. 2. Next step: build the heap, which initially is the singleton {entire_quadtree}. Then you'd iterate the loop to find the N minimal elements, at every step taking the B-minimal element of the subtree at the top of the heap. Initially, that means taking the B-minimal element of the whole quadtree (the only element of the heap at this point). Now you'll want to put the whole quadtree, minus its B-minimal element, back into the heap; I think the easiest way to do that might be to split the tree into (...)

Comment: (...) maximal subtrees that don't contain the B-minimal element and enter all of them into the heap. (Note that to be able to maintain heap order, every node of your quadtree will need to have a pointer to its B-minimal node; if you do it this way, with the splitting up, you can maintain that property easily.) To reiterate the key point here: the heap contains *subtrees*, not *domain elements*.

Comment: Erik: I'm still looking into this, I'll comment soon. BTW: isn't your description of the quadtree (cutting at the medians of alternating dimensions) technically a k-d tree?

Comment: Ah, "The Algorithm Design Manual" divides kd-trees into several flavors, of which a quadtree is one. Other sources seemed to view quadtrees as something of its own, especially when considering region quadtrees (instead of point quadtrees).

Comment: Erik: to clarify my doubts, I've drawn an example of the discussed case where [X,Y] matches all elements, including the quadtree (kd-tree), S set, and initial heap. Please see http://dl.dropbox.com/u/140506/query-kdtree-S-1.pdf and tell me if this what your proposed. If so, would it be possible for your to walk me through the next step, using the example data shown in the PDF? Thanks a lot!

Comment: (BTW, the format of the tree is (A, B), where the first level cuts the A dimension, the second level cuts the B dimension, etc)

Comment: @LuísMarques: yes, I would view quadtrees as the k=2 case of kd-trees. The example looks like the right setup - I thought of a tree with actual points only in the leaves and only bisection information in the internal nodes, but that shouldn't really make a difference for the algorithm. One thing you'd need to add, which I didn't think of initially but added in a previous comment, is a pointer in every node to the B-minimal node in the subtree rooted at that node. This gives you (46, 2) initially. You'd need to represent the remaining 30 nodes as a collection of subtrees; that would be (...)

Comment: (...) the subtrees rooted at (96, 52), (39, 51), (2, 9), and (45, 39), and four new one-node subtrees consisting of a single node in the path from root to (46, 2): viz. (51, 81), (50, 39), (30, 9), and (40, 8). (Since these guys are single-node trees, their B-minimal element is their only element.) So now we have 8 subtrees to insert into the (currently empty) heap. Remember that each node has a pointer to its B-minimal element, so we can insert the elements into the empty heap quickly. The subtree rooted at (2, 9) would be the top element of the heap (having the smallest B-minimal (...)

Comment: (...) element), and would be extracted from the heap to find the next-smallest element - (26, 7). You'd reinsert the existing subtree at (0, 33) into the heap (which happens to be single-node), and the new single-node subtree containing only (2, 9). The third element is obtained similarly. One potential optimization: it might be better to not insert all of these subtrees separately, but just create new internal nodes for the path from the element to be removed to the root; e.g. in the first step, create a new node (40, 8) with as single child node the existing (45, 39); a new node (30, 9)(...)

Comment: (...) with as children the existing subtree rooted at (2, 9) and the newly created node for (40, 8), and so on up to a new root node (51, 81) with as its children the existing (96, 52) and an also newly created (50, 39). This way, the heap would always contain at most the number of subtrees it started out with. You would still have to remove the old tree and reinsert the new one because the position in the heap might be different - in this case there would be just one subtree of course. (Any further discussion should maybe happen in chat...)

Comment: I haven't yet found the time to provide a (near-)final comment on this question. But, in summary, this solution seems good enough for the problem as stated, so I've accepted the answer. I'll send further comments later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The outcome you describe is what most search engines are built to achieve (sorting, filtering, paging). If you havent done so already, check out a search engine like Norch or Solr.